# Changing the time format in Ruby application

Tags: ruby

My current date format is `19:35`, but I want it to display as this format: `2013-07-29 7:13 UTC`.

How can I do this? My current code is `now = Time.now.gmtime.strftime("%H:%M")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
now = Time.now.gmtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %l:%M %Z")
```

That should do the trick

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
Time.now.utc
```

?

That prints the current time in UTC format.

Comment: [`Time.now.utc`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Time#utc-instance_method) returns another `Time` object. To make a string out of it, like you see in IRB, you have to do [`Time.now.utc.to_s`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Time#to_s-instance_method). And if you look at the code, you can see that `#to_s` on a UTC time actually just calls [`#strftime`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Time#strftime-instance_method) with the default format string `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC"`.